# Example of a poset with elements not included in a maximal element?

Tags: order-theory

I am reading Gratzer's *General Lattice Theory* and one of the exercises is to give an example of a poset with maximal elements in which not every element is included in a maximal element. I am struggling to see how this is possible. An element that is incomparable to all other elements would be a maximal element by default, so how can an element that is comparable to another element not be included in a maximal element?

The only possibility I can see is if you had a finite chain together with an infinite chain. So you would have a maximal element in the finite chain, but no maximal element in the infinite chain.

Are there any other examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a chain of order type $\Bbb Z$ and add an incomparable element "on the side". The incomparable element is maximal; but no element in the $\Bbb Z$ part is below a maximal element.

Comment: Yeah I guess there are a lot of little examples like that the more I think about it. I would venture to say that this situation is impossible in a finite poset though, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.